# gradle down missing directory

Tags: java, gradle, init

### I downloaded gradle 8.0.2 version. When I look at my gradle directory I see
\gradle-8.0.2-bin\gradle-8.0.2\bin
It has two files gradle and gradle.bat
When I run gradle init I see

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':wrapper' (type 'Wrapper').

  - In plugin 'org.gradle.buildinit.plugins.BuildInitPlugin$Inject' type 'org.gradle.api.tasks.wrapper.Wrapper' property 'jarFile' is not writable because 'C:\Users\baigk\Downloads\gradle-8.0.2-bin\gradle-8.0.2\bin\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.jar' ancestor 'C:\Users\baigk\Downloads\gradle-8.0.2-bin\gradle-8.0.2\bin\gradle' is not a directory.

    Reason: Cannot create parent directories that are existing as file.

    Possible solution: Configure 'jarFile' to point to the correct location.

Comment: I have used gradle older versions before and never saw this issue. I am also using Java 19.0.0

Comment: I deleted and restarted using C:\Gradle\gradle-8.0.2 and keep getting settings.gradle already exists

Comment: Now I keep getting settings.gradle already exists